# No content visible in django-bootstrap3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates

I am using Django 1.9 and demo template structure to display home.html.
I have included the following in the base.html file:

```
{% block bootstrap3_content %}
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    ...
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  {% autoescape off %}{% bootstrap_messages %}{% endautoescape %}
  {% block content %}(no content){% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Navbar shows successfully but I do not get the Bootstrap message in the container below?
I am a new user to Django and this App as well. Please help!

### Edit1:

`bootstrap.html` extends `bootstrap3.html`; `base.html` extends bootstrap.html; `home.html` extends `base.html`.
home.html

```
{% block title %}My_title{% endblock %} 
{% block content %} This is <em>bootstrap3</em> for <strong>Django</strong>. 
{% endblock %}
```

I get the title in the navbar but no message inside `content` block.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
```

at the top of your page since you are using this module. Make sure that you have

```
'bootstrap3',
```

in your installed apps.

From your code it looks like you are extending a template. If you are, be sure to have a

```
{% extends FooTemplate.html %}
```

in case you are loading boostrap3 in the parent template.

Comment: I have {% load bootstrap3 %} within base template file. 
Have 'bootstrap3' in INSTALLED_APPS list.